# Php pdo mysql not found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, centos, php-extension

I have already done much digging on installing/enabling PDO mysql extension on stackoverflow and many other sites, so please do not consider this as a duplicate question

I am on centos 6.5 and has php 5.5.26 which was compiled with `make, make install` (I know this is an older version so please do not close question or suggest updating to new php version. Also cannot install php using yum as this is what has been installed already me and should not be installed/changed).

So when I did compile php and added it to apache, it does not show mysql PDO driver. I tried putting `extension=pdo_mysql.so` to `ini` file with no success (yes I did restart the server as well, after making changes).

It shows pdo enabled, but only for drivers pgsql and sqlite.

Also, tried installing php-mysql package using yum. But the issue with yum installation is it installs 5.3.3 version of driver which complains about compatibility issues as my php version is 5.5.26.

So I am not sure what I need to do install pdo mysql extension

Comment: Just need to ask the basic questions - did you restart php and your web server?

Comment: Of course I did restart server.

Comment: Thought so. If you can't recompile with --with-pdo-mysql, can't install the extension through yum, and can't upgrade, I have no idea what you can do about it. Best of luck, I hope you find a good answer.

Comment: have you tried installing php-mysql via yum without taking under consideration the compatibility issues? As i remember you have that option. And after that installation try to uninstall only php 5.3.3. I think more or less this is probably what you have to do.

Comment: @PeterDarmis I did try that, but when I restart php, it throws error in log `Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212`

Comment: i think this might happen because php 5.3.3 is not completely uninstalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Peter Darmis was right from his comments.

PHP 5.3.3 was not completely uninstalled, don't know why.

There was already a PHP installed manually be compilation and, as I wasn't aware about this, I was using `yum` for installation of modules and at that time PHP 5.3.3 got installed which I don't know why it dot un-install properly.

So I ended up with 2 PHP versions, so uninstalled PHP 5.3.3 completely using `yum` and then resolved this issue compiling PHP with pdo options